# Improving loop through xml files ad add to DF

Tags: python, xml, pandas

With this code, i loop through similar xml files and add them to a DataFrame.

How can i make this code better so it is more pythonic?

```
Dados = pd.DataFrame([])

folder = os.listdir(path)

for file in folder:
    if file.endswith('.xml'):
        with open(os.path.join(path, file), encoding="utf8") as fd:
           doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
           if 'InformeMensal' in doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros'].keys():
               DadosEconomicoFinanceiros = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']

               NomeFundo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['DadosGerais']['NomeFundo']
               CNPJFundo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['DadosGerais']['CNPJFundo']
               NomeAdministrador = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['DadosGerais']['NomeAdministrador']
               PublicoAlvo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['DadosGerais']['PublicoAlvo']
               InformeMensal = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']
               InformeMensalCotistas = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Cotistas']
               if '@total' in doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Cotistas'].keys():
                   TotalCotistas = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Cotistas']['@total']
               pass
               if not '@total' in doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Cotistas'].keys():
                   TotalCotistas = "0"
               pass
               if 'FundosInvImobiliario' in doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Cotistas'].keys():
                   FIIsCotistas = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Cotistas']['FundosInvImobiliario']
               pass
               if not 'FundosInvImobiliario' in doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Cotistas'].keys():
                   FIIsCotistas = "0"
               pass
               InformeMensalResumo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']
               Ativo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']['Ativo']
               PatrimonioLiquido = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']['PatrimonioLiquido']
               NumCotasEmitidas = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']['NumCotasEmitidas']
               ValorPatrCotas = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']['ValorPatrCotas']
               DespesasTxAdministracao = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']['DespesasTxAdministracao']
               DespesasAgCustodiante = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']['DespesasAgCustodiante']
               RentEfetivaMensal = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']['RentEfetivaMensal']
               AmortizAcoesCotas = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Resumo']['AmortizAcoesCotas']

               InformeMensalInformacoesAtivo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesAtivo']

               TotalNecessidadesLiq= doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesAtivo']['TotalNecessidadesLiq']
               TotalInvestido= doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesAtivo']['TotalInvestido']
               ValoresReceber= doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesAtivo']['ValoresReceber']
               InformeMensalInformacoesPassivo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']
               RendimentosDistribuir = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['RendimentosDistribuir']
               TxAdministracaoPagar = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['TxAdministracaoPagar']
               TxPerformancePagar = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['TxPerformancePagar']
               ObrigacoesAquisicaoImov = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['ObrigacoesAquisicaoImov']
               AdiantamentoVendaImov = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['AdiantamentoVendaImov']
               AdiantamentoAlugueis = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['AdiantamentoAlugueis']
               ObrigacoesSecRecebiveis = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['ObrigacoesSecRecebiveis']
               InstrumentosFinanceirosDeriv = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['InstrumentosFinanceirosDeriv']
               ProvisoesContigencias = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['ProvisoesContigencias']
               OutrosValoresPagar = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['OutrosValoresPagar']
               TotalPassivo = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['InformacoesPassivo']['TotalPassivo']

               Data = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']['Cotistas'] ['@data_informacao']

Dados = Dados.append(pd.DataFrame({'Data':Data,'Nome': NomeFundo, 'CNPJ': CNPJFundo,'NomeAdministrador':NomeAdministrador,'PublicoAlvo':PublicoAlvo,'CotistasTotal':TotalCotistas,'FIIsCotistas':FIIsCotistas,'Ativo':Ativo,'PatrimonioLiquido':PatrimonioLiquido,'NumCotasEmitidas':NumCotasEmitidas,'ValorPatrCotas':ValorPatrCotas,'DespesasTxAdministracao':DespesasTxAdministracao,'DespesasAgCustodiante':DespesasAgCustodiante,'RentEfetivaMensal':RentEfetivaMensal,'AmortizAcoesCotas':AmortizAcoesCotas,'TotalNecessidadesLiq':TotalNecessidadesLiq, 'TotalInvestido':TotalInvestido, 'ValoresReceber':ValoresReceber,'RendimentosDistribuir':RendimentosDistribuir, 'TxAdministracaoPagar':TxAdministracaoPagar, 'TxPerformancePagar':TxPerformancePagar, 'ObrigacoesAquisicaoImov':ObrigacoesAquisicaoImov,'AdiantamentoVendaImov':AdiantamentoVendaImov, 'AdiantamentoAlugueis':AdiantamentoAlugueis, 'ObrigacoesSecRecebiveis':ObrigacoesSecRecebiveis,'InstrumentosFinanceirosDeriv':InstrumentosFinanceirosDeriv, 'ProvisoesContigencias':ProvisoesContigencias, 'OutrosValoresPagar':OutrosValoresPagar, 'TotalPassivo':TotalPassivo}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Could you add some more info on the intent here? There's a huge amount of non-english words, so it's hard to determine the intent behind your code. Some inline comments might help get you some better feedback.

Comment: Also, extracting variables is probably a good place to start, so that there is less duplication. In fact, it looks like you do that: `InformeMensal = doc['DadosEconomicoFinanceiros']['InformeMensal']`, but you don't reuse that variable, when you could on nearly every following line, and that would make it more readable, most likely. Generally it's more clear when there is only one index (`[]`) or `.` in a row, although there are exceptions to that rule.

Comment: These are balance sheets of Brazilian real estate funds, that's why the non English words, but those are just the keys inside the 'doc' dict created by XMLtodict. I loop through all xml in folder and append these keys values to the df Dados

Comment: Please include your `import` statements as well. While most of them look like they are standards, `xmltodict` does not.

Comment: Also, what does the XML structure look like? It seems to be the same for all files (otherwise you couldn't hardcode extracting the values), but do you e.g extract all fields, or only some?